# Connecting to SharePoint 2010 From the Internet (Keep being prompted for my Username & Password)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos, sharepoint-2010, ntlm, credentials

I installed Sharepoint Server 2010 on a domain controller but when I want to connect to my team site or my document workspace through the internet it keeps prompting me to enter my username and password.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2, I have an ADSL Modem Router and I have forwarded all ports from 1 to 65000 in my router. I have also disabled my firewall as well but it still it keeps prompting me for my credentials over and over again.

I have also configured TFS2010 in my Server and also i use sql server 2008 R2 and they are all installed in domain controller. I have no problems accessing TFS over the internet but Sharepoint keeps asking for my username and password, It seems to work fine on my local network but when I try to access it through the internet I keep having this problem.

Comment: I'd be very wary about disabling firewalls on Domain Controllers.  I'd also be very wary about installing server software (other than Active Directory) on a  domain controller.  You should take as many steps to protect your domain controllers as you can.

Comment: Opening all those ports is an issue.  Be sure you are fully patched.  Is the system you are using to access on the domain and do you use your domain credentials to log on to that system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you have kerberos setup instead of NTLM on the sharepoint site?

http://mbar.nl/michel/archive/2009/11/16/sharepoint-2010-and-kernel-mode-authentication.aspx

Also, are you entering "domain\username" or "username@domain.com" when logging in externally?  Instead of just "username"?

Answer (score 0):

For NTLM and SPNEGO (Kerberos) authentication, credentials of the user currently logged-in are used. This means that the workstation you use must be in same (or otherwise related) AD domain.